# Setting a field that doesnt exist to a value when selecting

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm going 2 tables together, the query is working fine. However, finding it difficult to work out which row belongs to which table.

I have a Clients table and a Projects table. Ideally when querying I want to add a field named `type` and set that to either clients or projects.

Can I do this with MySQL?

I'm using laravel's querybuilder, and here's my query.

```
 DB::table('clients')
        ->select(['clients.id', 'clients.name'])
        ->where('clients.organisation_id', '=', $organisation->id)
        ->where('clients.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->join('projects', function($join) use ($query){
            $join->on('clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
                ->select(['projects.id', 'projects.name'])
                ->where('projects.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
        })
        ->get()
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer with any more details. Could you share your current query so we have something concrete to refer to?

Comment: I'm using laravel's Eloquent, so I'll add the query now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects)s mention that you can add an `AS` clause just like in SQL so this should work:

```
 DB::table('clients')
        ->select(['clients.id AS client_id', 'clients.name AS client_name'])
        ->where('clients.organisation_id', '=', $organisation->id)
        ->where('clients.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->join('projects', function($join) use ($query){
            $join->on('clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
                ->select(['projects.id AS project_id', 'projects.name AS project_name'])
                ->where('projects.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
        })
        ->get()
```

This way, you end up with fields prefixed with the table name (`client_id`  vs `project_id`) so confusion is impossible.

Comment: Hmm, this doesnt' work. It calls the rows client_id and client_name despite the projects being projects?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a [Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) on your database and call this in your code. In the SP, you can use `if else`, so you can check if it's a client or a project and set a variable which you can output then.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping your selects together in the same query instead of the nested join:

```
DB::table('clients')
    ->select([
        'clients.id AS client_id',
        'clients.name AS client_name',
        'projects.id AS project_id',
        'projects.name AS project_name'
    ])
    ->join('projects', 'clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
    ->where('clients.organisation_id', '=', $organisation->id)
    ->where('clients.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
    ->where('projects.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
    ->get()
```